# The Easiest Way to Change 'DIV' Content On All Pages At Once

Tags: php, css, html

Certain DIVs within a website can usually be constant...

I.E. The footer of a webpage generally doesn't change and should be standard across all pages.

Within a websites CSS, you'll have things like;

```
.FooterDIV {
     Background: #FFFFFF;
     Color: #000000;
 }
```

I was wondering what the best way is to specify the standard text within a DIV, is this possible in CSS alone? PHP perhaps?

After some 'Googling' I have found no clear answer - it's difficult to know how to word this.

Comment: What's wrong with the sample you provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach is to put those "global" elements into a seperate php file each, which you include in all of your pages. For example:

footer.php

```
<div>Copyright 2012, Acme Corp.</div>
```

Then simply add the following line wherever you want the footer to appear

```
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: This looks like the ticket, and my CSS would still style this 'Footer' as if I had typed the HTML in without the PHP?

Comment: If your CSS file in which you declared the styles for your footer is loaded, it will apply all styles as before. The page is rendered completely before it is delivered to the user/browser, so there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

> Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) is a style sheet language used for
>   describing the presentation semantics (the look and formatting) of a
>   document written in a markup language.

i.e. you should CSS to style your data. You shouldn't be using it to specify what your data is. Surely there's a better way of approaching your problem? Like splitting up reoccurring elements/divs on your site into include files?

Answer (score 0):

That is usually done server side, in PHP for your case, you create a function that writes your html footer, you then call this function for any of your php pages.

Also if you are using a template engine, like when you are using a MVC PHP framework, then the template engine will usually let you create a template file with your footer content, and you will include that same file on all your different page templates.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing can't be done in css. If you're using php, I would seperate the footer out into at seperate file, e.g. 'footer.php' and then [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) that at the bottom of each of your pages.